# How to limit PHP's total memory usage across apache

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, memory-management, cakephp-2.x

So, neither I nor my colleague can find an answer to our question. HOW do we limit PHP's total memory usage on apache?

We are running CakePHP 2.x on an EC2 instance on AWS, the instance has 15GB of memory. I know that in the php.ini file there is a memory_limit={GB/MB} that according to the PHP [docs](http://php.net/memory-limit) limits the amount of memory any single script can use. So how do we enable this same type of limit on PHP as a whole? We are running PHP v5.4 on Apache 2.4. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not at all. PHP uses memory scriptwise as you already found out. But you can limit apache to execute a specific amount of PHP scripts at the same time.

Comment: Do you know how to do this @MarkusZeller ?

Comment: It is not possible. But an idea would be to launch a docker container with limited resources and call all php within there.

Answer (score -1):

Ohh i see. You can't do that with php language. You would have to limit the apache server memory. As well i don't thats possible. But you can optimize your server cpu usage (number of processes and threads) and use the **php.ini** `memory_limit = 128M` which will limit memory usage per process.

You can edit your **conf\extra\httpd-mpm.conf** and manage it:

```
# prefork MPM

# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves

# before terminating
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers          5
    MaxSpareServers         10
    MaxRequestWorkers      250
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello, this is not very useful as I said that that setting doesn't do what we need.

Answer (score -1):

It depends majorly on you logic, if there is a specific code block where you need to assign more memory to process.
There are 2 ways.

- memory_limit from php.ini
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php
- Check and get the instance of EC2 which suits your needs / offers your memory requirement.